# Call random methods in Android

Tags: java, android, random, onclick

I have a question that I really don't know if it's possible realize it. This is the situation; I have five methods and one button. Actually if I want call a method tapping the button I write:

```
    btnore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //i call the method I need
            Met_one();
        }
    });
```

What I need is do something like:

```
    btnore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // a random function call the methods. 
            Random = random of the methods(Met_one,     Met_two,Met_three,Met_four,Met_five)
        }   
    });
```

So in this way when I tap the button sometimes it does a kind of action and sometimes another one at random. It's it possible?

Comment: A simple approach would be generating a random number from 1 to 5, then on a switch statement you execute one method or another according the random number you get.

Comment: @ClaudioRedi's obvious solution in the comment above will attract a few copy-cat answers -- pick Sergey's :)

Comment: Can you show me please an example? O se sei italiano, potresti postare un esempio? :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the best solution is to use switch with random numbers

Something like this:

```
Random random = new Random();
int numberOfMethods = 4;

switch(random.nextInt(numberOfMethods)) {
     case 0: 
          method1();
          break;
     case 1: 
          method2();
          break;
     case 2: 
          method3();
          break;
     case 3: 
          method4();
          break;
     default: 
     method1();
}
```

Comment: Instead of `nextInt() % numberOfMethods` just use `nextInt( numberOfMethods )`

Comment: Why provide the default at all?  Or alternatively, why isn't `case 3:` actually `default`?

Comment: Yes default section here is really useless.

Answer (score 1):

In java  `Math.random() * 5` This would return a value in the range [0,5].when you press the Button you can invoke it.

inside the `onCreate`

```
Button btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
btn1.setOnClickListener(btnOnClickListener);
```

and

```
Button.OnClickListener btnOnClickListener=new Button.OnClickListener()
    {

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {

          if(v==b1)
{
// your Math.random() * 5 function can invoke.
}

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. If you have fixed number methods, the probability is going to be 1/n. Eg, with 5, probability is 0.2. You can have something like this, where rand is re-generated every time the button is clicked:

```
if (rand < 0.2)
    Met_one()
else if (rand < 0.4)
    Met_two()
else if (rand < 0.6)
    Met_three()
... etc
```

Comment: rand is a random number you generate between 0 to 1. Check Math.random() in Java. Doesn't have to be between 0 to 1, you can have for instance from 0 to 100. If you have two functions, in 50% of the time you'll go to met_one(); 50% for met_two. If you have three, you'll go to each one in 33% of the time, etc.

Comment: @323go: I'm sure that tone wasn't necessary. Can you elaborate on why this is so horrible in your opinion?

Comment: It's horribly inefficient and cluttered. A `switch` statement would have been the natural selection for this, which means `rand` needs to be `integer`, leading as to `Random.nextInt`. A string of `if else` statements over a float is just poor design. The byte code generated by a `switch` is also considerably more succinct, while @Hajjat's proposed "solution" would result in several float comparisons.

Comment: It's just a quick sketch of the high level idea, the specifics of implementation are left to the programmer. I don't think we're supposed to spoon-feed answers.

Comment: If you're going to make wild claims about horrible inefficiency then you should back them up with numbers. There is virtually no difference in performance between these 5 `if` statements compared to a `switch` and "cluttered" is very subjective: there's hardly a difference between `case 1` and `else if(rand < 0.4)`.

Comment: There are no wild claims. Switch statements are converted to jump tables, while if statements are serially executed. Since you brought up reflection, I'm sure you know enough about java's inner workings to know this? As far as answering a "high level idea," the asker clearly had that -- randomly calling one of five functions. He asked for an efficient implementation, not a rephrasing of his question.

Comment: @323go Totally disagree.  I never use `switch` (in Java) at all.  It is ugly, has the missing `break`, fall-through issue, only works for int (okay, String too now, in later Java) and has to be refactored as soon as one of the conditions becomes anything other than a trivial literal value.  Also, efficiency is irrelevant here: its UI code (but would still be irrelevant in 99.9% of all such code ever written, anyway).  Hajjat's solution also lets you easily bias the choice (if desired).  The one caveat I would raise would be it you wanted each choice to be *exactly* as probable, though.

Comment: Ok, yes you should have used an integer here. But this optimization discussion is _premature_.  The code is being run in an onclick listener.  Hardly a place where you need to worry about the overhead of a few if statements.

Comment: @Paul, I'd use literal values only in cases like this -- one would generally use identifiers in other cases, or, preferably, enums.

Comment: @323go To clarify, by literal I didn't mean 'typed in literally' as opposed to say, declared as a `public static final int FOO = 42;` or a value from an Enum.  Rather I meant the value in the `case` can't be a variable, a computed value, or one returned by a method, etc.